# Which xfce4-window theme is this?

Tags: 12.04, themes, xfce

I found this image on the xfce4-slideshow but I cant find it in my xfce.
What is the name of this theme?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme's name is **greybird**. It seems to be included by default in Xubuntu 12.04.

I've installed and using it right now. See this screenshot:

[image]

You can have the theme by installing `shimmer-themes` package.

```
sudo apt-get install shimmer-themes
```

Hope this will help.